# DavidWebb Android Main Thread Exception

Tags: android, multithreading

I seem to be getting a MainThreadException on Android even though I am running on another thread. Code and trace below. Can anyone advise me on what I am doing wrong below. Unless I am mistaken, the postDelayed() handler is not on the main thread, and it calls register() from within it, which in turn invokes the DavidWebb code. What am I missing?

```
    final boolean b = new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (register(name, email, password)) {
                            onSignupSuccess();
                        } else {
                            onSignupFailed();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }, 3000);


    private boolean register(String name, String email, String password) {
        String json = "{ "
                    + "\"tenant\" :  {"
                    + "\"name\" : \"" + name + "\""
                    + "},"
                    + "\"user\" : {"
                    + "\"email\" : \"" + email + "\","
                    + "\"password\" : \"" + encryptPassword(password) + "\""
                    + "}"
                     + "}";

        Webb webb = Webb.create();
        webb.setDefaultHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        Response<JSONObject> response =      webb.post(bigskyRegister).body(json).asJsonObject();
        if (!response.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Auth fail: " + response.getStatusCode() +
                    " - " + response.getResponseMessage());
            webb.delete(bigskyRegister).asVoid();
            return false;
        }

        webb.delete(bigskyRegister).asVoid();
        return false;
    }

Stack trace:
com.goebl.david.WebbException: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at com.goebl.david.Webb.execute(Webb.java:329)
            at com.goebl.david.Request.asJsonObject(Request.java:257)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity.register(SignupActivity.java:145)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity.access$000(SignupActivity.java:22)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity$3.run(SignupActivity.java:79)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1147)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:106)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:217)
            at com.goebl.david.Webb.writeBody(Webb.java:361)
            at com.goebl.david.Webb.execute(Webb.java:295)
            at com.goebl.david.Request.asJsonObject(Request.java:257)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity.register(SignupActivity.java:145)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity.access$000(SignupActivity.java:22)
            at com.vmware.bsky.SignupActivity$3.run(SignupActivity.java:79)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

Comment: How do you create your handler? Can you add that code as well?

Answer (score 0):

Log says all... Use thread/AsyncTask/Service for Network operations.

[image]